# Reference for the multiprojective Nullstellensatz?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

[Crossposted at MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368507/reference-for-the-multiprojective-nullstellensatz)

I'm looking for a reference to a generalization of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to the multiprojective setting. This seems to be a basic fact but I'm having trouble finding a statement online or in the literature.

Consider the product $$\mathbb P=\mathbb P(\mathbb C^{n_1})\times\dots\times \mathbb P(\mathbb C^{n_k}).$$ Let $R$ be the ring of polynomials in variables $X_i^j$ with $j\in[1,k]$ and $i\in[1,n_j]$. Let $I\subset R$ be a *multihomogeneous* ideal meaning that $I$ is homogeneous with respect to degree in the variables $X_1^j,\dots,X_{n_j}^j$ for every $j$. Then $I$ is seen to define a subset $V(I)\subset\mathbb P$ of points in which all $p\in I$ vanish. **Question:** where in the literature can I find a necessary and sufficient condition for $I$ to contain *all* polynomials vanishing on $V(I)$? (Preferably in a standard reference such as Hartshorne.)

(I suspect that the condition is that $I$ is a) multihomogeneous, b) radical and c) saturated with respect to the irrelevant ideals $\langle X_1^j,\dots,X_{n_j}^j\rangle$ for all $j$. I think I know how this can be proved but I'm looking for a precise reference.)

Comment: [Crossposted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368507/reference-for-the-multiprojective-nullstellensatz). When crossposting, it's important to link all versions to avoid duplicating work. Further, the generally-accepted community guidance on how long to wait between crossposts is ["a week"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo) or so, not simply a day.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the comment, I added a link to the MO question. To be honest, my experience with both of these websites (mostly MO) tells me that if there was no reaction (not even a comment) within the first 24 hours or so, receiving an answer after that is very unlikely.

Comment: You're still missing a link from this post to the MO version. The references I have found so far in the literature I'm familiar with leave this sort of thing to the reader - Fulton's Algebraic Curves' section on multiprojective spaces is basically "do it yourself, use the Segre embedding", Hartshorne doesn't mention multiprojective space (though he does give you the tools to prove what you want), etc. Depending on what you're writing and for what audience you might just prove this yourself - adding references for something that should be in the literature in a thesis is a bit of a tradition.

Comment: Thanks but I'm writing a paper where a detailed proof of such a fact would certainly be out of place. Needless to say, if a (somewhat reputable) source gives this statement without a proof, e.g. as an exercise, it will be good enough for me.